# HTTPS with Poco: Certificate verify failed

Tags: c++, ssl, https, poco-libraries

I'm trying to get HTTPS running using the POCO library using this little program:

```
int main()
{
    // For debugging purposes to inspect verification errors.
    SharedPtr<InvalidCertHandler> invalidCertHandler(new InvalidCertHandler());

    URI uri("https://google.com/");

    Context::Ptr ctx = new Context(Context::CLIENT_USE, "", Context::VerificationMode::VERIFY_RELAXED, 9, true);
    SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(nullptr, invalidCertHandler, ctx);
    HTTPSClientSession httpSession(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), ctx);
    HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, uri.getPath(), HTTPRequest::HTTP_1_1);
    HTTPResponse response;

    try
    {
        httpSession.sendRequest(request);
        httpSession.receiveResponse(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cout << ex.message() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Success" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I always get the following exception message when running the program:

```
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

And the following message in my `InvalidCertHandler`:

```
unable to get local issuer certificate
```

After that I opened `https://google.com/`in `Google Chrome` and exported the certificate in `Base64-encoded X.509 Format (.CER)` and initialized the `Context` with the absolute path of the `.cer` file instead of just an empty string. That didn't work too.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here but I would like to know.
Can anyone of you help me out on this?

Comment: Are you using `VERIFY_RELAXED` for a specific reason?

Comment: It's enabled by default but I need to pass this argument to pass the boolean argument loadDefaultCAs

Comment: It seems like you are trying to verify Google's cert. Google typically has intermediate certificates in its chain, so you will have to add all the intermediate CAs presented by `www.google.com` to your trusted store to get this to work. If you don't want to perform certificate verification, I would try `VERIFY_NONE`.

Comment: @Rahul: Oh yeah it works. You're my hero of the day!